# Bitnami Redis on Kubernetes Authentication Failure with Existing Secret

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm trying to install Redis on Kubernetes environment with [Bitnami Redis HELM Chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis). I want to use a defined password rather than randomly generated one. But i'm getting error below when i want to connect to redis master or replicas with redis-cli.

```
I have no name!@redis-client:/$ redis-cli -h redis-master -a $REDIS_PASSWORD 
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
Warning: AUTH failed
```

I created a Kubernetes secret like this.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: redis-secret
  namespace: redis
type: Opaque
data:
  redis-password: YWRtaW4xMjM0Cg==
```

And in values.yaml file i updated auth spec like below.

```
auth:
  enabled: true
  sentinel: false
  existingSecret: "redis-secret"
  existingSecretPasswordKey: "redis-password"
  usePasswordFiles: false
```

If i don't define `existingSecret` field and use randomly generated password then i can connect without an issue. I also tried `AUTH admin1234` after `Warning: AUTH failed` error but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was about how i encoded password with echo command. There was a newline character at the end of my password. I tried with printf command rather than echo and it created a different result.

```
printf admin1234 | base64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it in much simpler way i.e. by running:

```
$ helm install my-release \
  --set auth.password="admin1234" \
    bitnami/redis
```

This will update your `"my-release-redis"` secret, so when you run:

```
$ kubectl get secrets my-release-redis -o yaml
```

you'll see it contains your password, already `base64`-encoded:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  redis-password: YWRtaW4xMjM0Cg==
kind: Secret
...
```

In order to get your password, you need to run:

```
export REDIS_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default my-release-redis -o jsonpath="{.data.redis-password}" | base64 --decode)
```

This will set and export `REDIS_PASSWORD` environment variable containing your redis password.

And then you may run your `redis-client` pod:

```
kubectl run --namespace default redis-client --restart='Never'  --env REDIS_PASSWORD=$REDIS_PASSWORD  --image docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.4-debian-10-r13 --command -- sleep infinity
```

which will set `REDIS_PASSWORD` environment variable within your `redis-client` pod by assigning to it the value of `REDIS_PASSWORD` set locally in the previous step.

Comment: I tried to understand why i am unable to use existing secrets and tried with other charts to see if it is related with bitnami redis chart. But the problem was about my base64 encoding. There was a newline character at the end of my password because i encoded it like this;


`echo admin1234 | base64`


When i tried with printf it created a different result and i'm able to use existing secret now. It was a mistake on my side. Gonna post it as an answer. Thanks for the reply.


`printf admin1234 | base64`

Comment: You can still do it with `echo` command: `echo -n „password” | base64`. Simply add `-n` option (do not output the trailing newline).